# Proper way to refresh eclipse when updating UIBinder xml files?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, uibinder

I'm working on some GWT 2.4 uiBinder xml files and I'm seeing errors under the problems tab in eclipse indigo, even though nothing is wrong. ie  has no corresponding entry in the ui.xml file.

Doing a clean or refresh isn't fixing it, but shutting down eclipse each time and restarting isn't really a good option either.  Any ideas as to what I can do to get this refreshed in a timely manner without having to restart eclipse each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my mistake!  I have had eclipse get out of sync before with the uiBinder, but in this case I had some typos in my ui.xml file.

I was seeing this error:

**Field xxx has no corresponding field in template file yyy.ui.xml**

However, I could see that I had it named properly in both places.  What I missed was **ui_field="name"** etc... in the ui.xml file should have been **ui:field="name"** and when I corrected that everything resolved itself.